# R shiny not displaying numeric output

Tags: r, shiny, numeric

I am trying to get my R shiny app to display a wordcloud and also a textbox as output
The following are the two input dataframes based on which the process runs

```
d<-         word   frequency
            A       12
            with    11
            offers  10                   
            for     8

 DF4< -     word   frequency
            A       12
            with    11
            offers  10                   
            for     8
```

I have set up a UI with a text input- e mail subject. This links to action Button click me. The subject entered here is fed into the server and processed to create an output.

```
    ui<- fluidPage(
   textInput("e-mailSubject", label = "SubjectLine",placeholder = 
          "'"),actionButton("do", "Click Me"),
   numericInput("Audience Size", label = "Target Audience Size", value = 
             c(10000000)),
     dateInput("Date",label = "Date of Campaign"),
     mainPanel(plotOutput("Plot1"), textOutput("Output1")))
```

The Output1 should display. However, it is not. I am not getting any error message. The wordcloud is displaying.

```
  server<-function(input, output, session) {
  output$Plot1 <- renderPlot({
   set.seed(1234)
   wordcloud(words = d$word, freq = d$freq, min.freq = 1,
          max.words=200, random.order=FALSE, rot.per=0.35, 
          colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))   })
   output<-renderText(text2<-reactive({input$e-mailSubject
   mycorpus2<-Corpus(VectorSource(text2))
   mycorpus2<-tm_map(mycorpus2, tolower)
   mycorpus2<-tm_map(mycorpus2, removeNumbers)
   mycorpus2<-tm_map(mycorpus2, removeWords, c(stopwords("english")))
   #Encoding(text) <- "UTF-8"
   dtm2<-TermDocumentMatrix(mycorpus2)
   m2<-as.matrix(dtm2)
   v2 <- sort(rowSums(m2),decreasing=TRUE)
   d2 <- data.frame(word = names(v2),freq=v2)

  outputtable<-DF4[DF4$variable%in%d2$word,]
  outputresult<-sum(outputtable$sum.estimate.)
  return(outputresult)
  }))
   }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I request someone to help.

Comment: perhaps the white space in "Audience Size" ?

Comment: I have corrected that. it seems to work